# Laravel 5.5: filter queries from model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `Product Model`. A product has many variants, and I have this function in my `Product.php`

```
public function variants()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Variant', 'product_id');
}
```

I want to only show the Variants where the value for `is_published` is `1` so I tried this, like what I do in my controllers but it doesn't work, it still shows the variant even though the `is_published` is `0`.

```
public function variants()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Variant', 'product_id')->where('is_published', true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your should try this:

**Your Model**

```
public function variants()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Variant', 'product_id');
}

public function variants_publish() {
        return $this->variants()->where('is_published',true);
    }
```

Your controller query like:

```
$rsltDetails = YourModel::find(1);
var_dump( $rsltDetails->variants_publish()->get() );
```

Comment: @eibersji: If my answer work for you then please accept my answer

Answer (score -2):

Add the value of is_published 1 instead of true

```
public function variants()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Variant', 'product_id')->where('is_published', 1);
}
```